# How activate NVIDIA drivers?

Tags: 12.04, boot, drivers, nvidia, nouveau

Yesterday I was having a few memory leaks with Compiz, I decided to put this down to the new NVIDIA drivers that I installed.

I purged everything with NVIDIA from my system and booted into Ubuntu 12.04 with Nouveau. I noticed I couldn't install the drivers via jockey, the options were different.

it now read: Nvidia binary Xorg driver and it would even give me an error message when I did decide to install.

Luckily, I managed to install the NVIDIA drivers via the Xswat PPA and rebooted. Guess? My system booted into Nouveau again and I tried to blacklist via the modprob.d/config file and blacklisted old NVIDIA drivers and nouveau and still my system used the open source noveau drivers.

Does anyone know how to 'activate' the NVIDIA drivers? How can I check that they're even installed? Nvidia settings throws an error message warning me of no Xorg driver.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Dash and search for "Additional Drivers" . There you have an option to either Enable or Disable Nvidia drivers.

More Information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia).

Comment: There was no option for Nvidia Drivers. I managed to fix the issue by simply re-installing 12.04.